# Creating unique dataframe reading a file line by line

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a file.txt (tab separated) that needs to be changed into a dataframe, basically ordering the file reading line by line and creating unique columns for the final dataframe. Additionally, writing "Na" or empty value when no info is founded. Notice the "CS_" as a pattern after ":".
I was thinking about pandas dataframe but your help will be greatly appreciated. A suggestion in R could also be appreciated.

Input:

```
Japan        Cases:CS_1    People:CS_2    Life:CS_3
Australia    People:CS_4   Transportation:CS_Ground   
Spain        Life:CS_5     Language:CS_Spanish
```

Output:

```
             Cases     People    Life     Transportation     Language
Japan        CS_1      CS_2      CS_3     Na                 Na
Australia    Na        CS_4      Na       CS_Ground          Na
Spain        Na        Na        CS_5     Na                 CS_Spanish
```

Comment: One way would be to read the text file into a nested dict with the country as the outer key: `{'Japan': {'Cases': 'CS_1', 'People': CS_2', 'Life': 'CS_3'}, 'Australia': {...}, 'Spain': {...}}` and then iterate over the dict to get all the column names. Then create your dataframe.

Comment: Of course I use python because I have a huge datafile otherwise your solution will be way to go. I have thousands of rows and more than 10 different columns

Comment: Thousands of rows and tens of columns shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> infile = """Japan Cases:CS_1 People:CS_2 Life:CS_3
... Australia People:CS_4 Transportation:CS_Ground   
... Spain Life:CS_5 Language:CS_Spanish"""
```

Iterate through the file row-by-row:

1. Partition the first column from the rest
2. Split the rest with the appropriate delimiter (e.g. `\s` or `\t`)
3. Split each element into key-value pairs where the keys are the column headers you want in the final dataframe
4. Add the first column values (i.e. the country names)and use a temporary header name (e.g. `Key`)
5. Store the dictionary in a list

[code]:

```
>>> row_dicts = []
>>> for line in StringIO(infile):
...     k, _, therest =line.partition(' ')  # Step 1.
...     _row = {kv.split(':')[0]:kv.split(':')[1] for kv in therest.split()}  # Step 2-3. 
...     _row['Key'] = k  # Step 4. 
...     row_dicts.append(_row)  # Step 5.
...
```

Cast the list of dictionaries into a `pd.DataFrame`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(row_dicts)
  Cases        Key    Language  Life People Transportation
0  CS_1      Japan         NaN  CS_3   CS_2            NaN
1   NaN  Australia         NaN   NaN   CS_4      CS_Ground
2   NaN      Spain  CS_Spanish  CS_5    NaN            NaN
```

Use `.set_index` to set the country `Key` column as the index.

```
>>> df.set_index('Key')
          Cases    Language  Life People Transportation
Key                                                    
Japan      CS_1         NaN  CS_3   CS_2            NaN
Australia   NaN         NaN   NaN   CS_4      CS_Ground
Spain       NaN  CS_Spanish  CS_5    NaN            NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use (using a generator and a comprehension):

```
import re, pandas as pd

string = """
Japan        Cases:CS_1    People:CS_2    Life:CS_3
Australia    People:CS_4   Transportation:CS_Ground   
Spain        Life:CS_5     Language:CS_Spanish
"""

rx = re.compile(r'(?P<key>\w+):(?P<value>CS_\d+)')
rxc = re.compile(r'(?P<country>\w+)')

dft = (dict({'Country': item.group('country')}, **{m.group('key'): m.group('value') for m in rx.finditer(line)})
        for line in string.split("\n")
        for item in [rxc.match(line)]
        if item)

df = pd.DataFrame(dft)
print(df)
```

This uses two regular expressions, one for the country and one for the key/value pairs. Afterwards the `df` is constructed.